# how to override js function to another js file?

Tags: javascript, plugins, overriding

I am working on some plugin of java script. I am using that plugin in my Project.
Now there is needed some changes so i am changing that original js file and using that file. Now issue is when there is any update came, my changes has overridden or removed by that update. I am looking for how to override the original function from the original js file into new(mine) js file and how can i get updated version and can customize that file also?
please help.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript its possible to override nearly everything (not the prefered way, but possible)

So, if the orginal function is located on

> window.app.function1

you could just do this:

```
window.app.function1 = function() {
 // your code
}
```

This way is also called "monkey patching"